# Infer arguments of a function passed to a constructor

Tags: typescript

How can I infer the type of a function passed to a constructor ([TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAJiAOIDsYIMYE8CCAnA5gZwCgCVgBDPPCAWzQGEyKIBvAiCFAewTzCwFcUYDlgAUMeEkToAXBBGlZIgG6lgfELIR8qAIxBYAlBAC8APghKOASygAaCDsVGzF61GfnLNoyzZtxiMjoIsqq6praeoYm5kyc3BygAHTAHDihaiAGAL72Ih7M2QasENkEZQQIIADu1HQMeCFJzaS4eAUBkqiYbSYQrfjFBAD0wxAAkhDVpAiQQv0oABZWIEogEGCL6wBmICBQOqQoANYQ21gcVBtb7JdUiGCEnUE9%20AD8SQDaAAwAuiIAIlIAKMowmCBUwBs9iofB4DnWpAgWl0%20gIzykrzwHx%20-wAjKCxgA1VQ2IA))?

```
let dependencyArgs: SomeUtilityType<myClass>

class myClass {
  constructor(dependency: (a: (value: number) => void, b: () => void) => void) {
    dependency((value: number) => {console.log(value)}, () => {})
  }
}

new myClass((...args) => dependencyArgs = args)
// I want to achieve the feedback from the comments
dependencyArgs?.[0]("a") // Invalid, must be a number
dependencyArgs?.[0](1) // Valid
```

I tried it with a custom utility type ([TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwM7AE4FcDGw6oAqpxhIA8AKgHxQC8UZUEAHsBAgCZJQDeAUFFAggB3KAAoAhqgDmARgBcUAJYIAZhFRQAqgEoF4hCADcPAL5QA-FqgLBAN3XGeAGwjAoqCEjhP7AJQgAVhDYCniS4gC2ruqk8MhoWDj4hMQkoJBwKlAEcBGKSBAUFDyCIjl5BSQI6BEARuoUoqIAdK2oSNo0VB5ePhD%20Qdg07h1AA)):

```
type ConstructorProps<T> = T extends {
  new (arg1: infer U): any;
} ? U : never;

let resolveReject: Parameters<ConstructorProps<typeof Promise>>
new Promise<number>((...rs) => resolveReject = rs)
```

But it gives me this error:

```
Type '[resolve: (value: number | PromiseLike<number>) => void, reject: (reason?: any) => void]' is not assignable to type '[resolve: (value: unknown) => void, reject: (reason?: any) => void]'.
  Type at position 0 in source is not compatible with type at position 0 in target.
    Type '(value: number | PromiseLike<number>) => void' is not assignable to type '(value: unknown) => void'.
      Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.
        Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'number | PromiseLike<number>'.
          Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'PromiseLike<number>'.(2322)
```

So my custom utility types forgets that I passed number as a generic when I called `new Promise<number>()`

I also tried ([TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBATiDOD2wBuIBKIBWIDGYBcEAwvAHaxhQCuu8UACgIZQMC24IUsAPHVPCwEtYILiUosARhwB80gFAkQAdwi9%20QkWMkyAFDoB0hzgEoIAXmnQ4iFOiy5z0WMaA)):

```
let resolveReject: ConstructorParameters<Promise<number>>
new Promise<number>((...rs) => resolveReject = rs)
```

But this gives me:

```
Type 'Promise<number>' does not satisfy the constraint 'abstract new (...args: any) => any'.
  Type 'Promise<number>' provides no match for the signature 'new (...args: any): any'.(2344)
```

Edit:
I made some progress with the built-in utility type, but sadly I still cannot pass in the number type ([TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBATiDOD2wBuIBKIBWIDGYBcEACgIZTEC24IUsAPAMLwB2sYUArrvFCWZWNTpgAngAcQ8AGZEo8cgEtYIAHwBtAAwBdZQCgA9HogBlCiAjFY+w6EgwEyNJhz4ipUwJoNmrDlx5v+QVpCWQUlRhY2TjBuNS1dAwgAI3ZIbGImJnhIUQtYCFomdnIk6gTrcGg4RBR0LFwCXncgiJ9o7ibAzxFxKRk5RRBC4tKoZTjtHSYQAHd+sJAACkWAOjWaAEoIAF5lKvtap1wd6FgNqdn5weGSsuW1lc2dvbsax3rIbdOtxMZyUWAxHkLCAA)):

```
let resolveReject: Parameters<ConstructorParameters<typeof Promise>[0]>
// Same as
// let resolveReject: Parameters<ConstructorParameters<PromiseConstructor>[0]>
// but cannot pass <number>
// let resolveReject: Parameters<ConstructorParameters<typeof Promise<number>>[0]>
new Promise((...rs) => resolveReject = rs)
new Promise<number>((...rs) => resolveReject = rs) // Complains
```

Comment: can you please provide sample of the problem on https://www.typescriptlang.org/play ?

Comment: I updated the question

Answer (score 1):

```
type ConstructorProps<T> = T extends {
  new (dependency: (...args: infer U) => void): any;
} ? U : never;
```

You have to catch the parameters from the callback function `(/* ??? */) => void`, the first parameter of the constructor, which is filled with `[a: (value: number) => void, b: () => void]` in your `myClass` declaration.

The full solution will be:

```
let dependencyArgs: ConstructorProps<typeof myClass>

class myClass {
  constructor(dependency: (a: (value: number) => void, b: () => void) => void) {
    dependency((value: number) => {console.log(value)}, () => {})
  }
}

new myClass((...args) => dependencyArgs = args)

// I want to achieve the feedback from the comments
dependencyArgs?.[0]("a") // Invalid, must be a number
dependencyArgs?.[0](1) // Valid

type ConstructorProps<T> = T extends {
  new (dependency: (...args: infer U) => void): any;
} ? U : never;

let resolveReject: ConstructorProps<new () => Promise<number>>
new Promise<number>((...rs) => resolveReject = rs)
```